# Echo '<style'> in WordPress causes "Cannot modify header information" error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse74389_check_username');
function wpse74389_check_username(){
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if( current_user_can('admin')){
    echo '<style>
li#menu-settings .wp-submenu.wp-submenu-wrap li:last-child {
display: none!important;
}
li#menu-settings .wp-submenu.wp-submenu-wrap li:nth-child(2) {
 display: none!important;
}
</style>';
}
}
```

I receive an error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: `echo` the `style` added resulted in the action after this, including such as `session`, casting the error.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't undestand what you mean

Comment: are you trying to style your admin section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`admin_head` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head) to add the code to WP-Admin.

For example, replace your code with this:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wpse74389_check_username'); // <-- Modified

function wpse74389_check_username(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( current_user_can('admin')){
        echo '<style>
        li#menu-settings .wp-submenu.wp-submenu-wrap li:last-child {
        display: none!important;
        }
        li#menu-settings .wp-submenu.wp-submenu-wrap li:nth-child(2) {
        display: none!important;
        }
        </style>';
    }
}
```

The [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) fires too early in WordPress for you to directly `echo` code to screen. This is what causes the error message you're seeing.

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

This error often occurs if you attempt to print any text to screen (using `echo` or `print` or even having text before your opening `<?php` tag).

There's *lots* of information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php), which focus on causes of the error.